# Push notification implementation using service worker

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

`Service worker` functionality is supported by browsers now. And we can use web-push libraries to push notification to these service workers. But I am not clear what `firebase cloud messaging` or `gcm` does? `FCM` is a paid service and when we can do push notification using `service worker` and `web push library`, what is the role of `FCM`?

Comment: FCM is a **free** service.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have implemented the push notifications. But I haven't done any setup with FCM as mentioned in this link. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client . I want to know what is the advantage of using FCM over the basic push notification implementation that I did.

Comment: You're asking us to comment on something we can't see. More details please :-)